# Plotting "interior" and "exterior" convex hull of 3d shape

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, convex-hull, plane

I want to estimate the shape of convex 3d object. First let me give an example on 2d:

[image]

Lets say there is convex shape given by black color in the figure. We don't know its shape, but we are given points `A,B,C,D`. Using `convexhull` and `trisurf` commands on Matlab, we can plot "interior" convex hull given by blue color. Now, if we are given not only points `A,B,C,D` but also tangent lines to the black colored object through these points, we can plot "outer" convex hull through the points `A1,B1,C1,D1.` The "outer" convex hull is more difficult to plot, because there are many points where tangent lines intersect, so we need to find some way to obtain specifically `A1,B1,C1,D1`.

In 3d, we are given the points and tangent planes to these points in terms of plane equations `ax+by+cz=d`. Here is Matlab program that generates next two figures:

```
load("planedata.mat");
load("planedata_d.mat");
load("points.mat");

a=planedata(1:100,1);
b=planedata(1:100,2);
c=planedata(1:100,3);
d=planedata_d;

figure(1)
x = points(1,:); y = points(2,:); z = points(3,:);
[k1,av1] = convhull(x,y,z);
trisurf(k1,x,y,z);                    %plot interior convex hull
xlabel('$X$','Interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$Y$','Interpreter','latex');
zlabel('$Z$','Interpreter','latex');

figure(2)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
for i=1:100
    Z=real(-(a(i)*X+b(i)*Y+d(i))/c(i));
    hold on
    surf(X,Y,Z);                      %plot exterior convex hull
end
xlim([-1 2])
ylim([-1 2])
zlim([0 4])
xlabel('$X$','Interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$Y$','Interpreter','latex');
zlabel('$Z$','Interpreter','latex');
```

You can download the data file from [here](https://file.io/9qcewoGBG4KY). First, we just plot "interior" convex hull for given points:

[image]

Then the tangent planes:

[image]

And also I can see the shape of the "exterior" convex hull only by cutting all planes at specific height like this:

[image]

Is there any way to remove all the planes and plot only the "exterior" convex hull, so the figure looks like "interior" convex hull, but of course a little larger in size?

Comment: Since you have the interior convex hull, you can extimate the shapes' centre. Then, for each resonable density of angles, you can find the plane closest to the centre point. The last step then would be to find the intersection of the outer tangent planes, such that only the portion which is closer to the centre than other plane-parts remains.

Comment: @Adriaan what if instead of plane equations, we are given plane inequalities like ax+by+cz>=d or ax+by+cz<=b, so they become half spaces. So given many half spaces, is there any way to plot the shape which is bounded by these half spaces?

Comment: @Lee in your datafiles, is there information that tells to which nodes is any particular node connected to? Otherwise, would it be easy for this to be computed? I am asking because that knowledge (connections) will enable you to compute the intersections of the planes corresponding to some node `n` and its connections to nodes `n+1` and `n+2`. You would repeat this process now with nodes `n`, `n+2`, and `n+3` until you've spanned all of `n's` connections. Keep track of which nodes you have calculated the outer convex shell coordinates with to avoid repetitious calculations.

Comment: @J.A.Ferrand unfortunately there is no node connection information. I am given the points on the closure of convex body and the tangent planes to those points only.

Comment: @Lee are you sure? I looked up the documentation of `trisurf`, and that `k1` variable in your script (according to the MATLAB documentation) is an interconnectivity matrix. I believe this information is available in `k1`.

Comment: @J.A.Ferrand sorry for late reply, it took me a while to understand your suggestion and trisurf function. I think I managed to find intersection of planes, so currently I have many line functions: a point and direction vector. But still unable to complete the problem, because lines also intersect in many points, and I don't know how to choose most inner line intersections

Comment: @Lee I refer you to this resource: <https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html?searchHighlight=trisurf&s_tid=srchtitle#mw_daa402dc-28cb-4079-bf5c-7275340c1d4c> It is the MATLAB documentation on `trisurf`. I am pretty sure that your `k1` variable has what you need, the MATLAB documentation states that the point connections are specified via coordinates, not indices, unfortunately. I think if you do a boolean comparison between the rows of `k1` and those of  `[x',y',z']` you will know the connectivity and thus know which planes to intersect to produce the nodes of the outer shell.